# Why does setting ListView.View blow away my custom ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, listview, controltemplate

I have a custom control that inherits from ListView. I've defined a custom template for it and it works the way it's supposed to. However, when I define a view for my list view the custom template does not seem to be applied.

Here's what I'm doing:

My control:

```
public class TestListView : ListView
{
    static TestListView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestListView)));
    }

    public TestListView() : base(){}
}
```

My custom template:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:TestListView}" TargetType="{x:Type local:TestListView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="foo!" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Header="With View">
        <local:TestListView>
            <ListViewItem>One</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Two</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Three</ListViewItem>
            <local:TestListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="MyColumn" />
                </GridView>
            </local:TestListView.View>
        </local:TestListView>
    </GroupBox>

    <GroupBox Header="With No View">
        <local:TestListView>
            <ListViewItem>One</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Two</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Three</ListViewItem>
        </local:TestListView>
    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's what happens:
[image: Results]

I can get the expected results by explicitly declaring the style (`Style="{StaticResource {x:Type local:TestListView}}"`) or if the style is defined in the same file as the control (not in Generic.xaml or some other resource dictionary).

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Works for me in both cases though.

Comment: See updates. I discovered that this particular behavior doesn't occur when I defined the style in the same file as the control (e.g. in Windows.Resources), only when the style is in Generic.xaml or some other resource dictionary.